# (Purescript) How do I pattern match on an algebraic data type that is the "empty type"

Tags: pattern-matching, equality, algebraic-data-types, purescript

I'm working with the following algebraic data type in PureScript...

```
data Extended a = Infinite | Finite a

v1 = Finite 11
v2 = Infinite
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pattern match the "Infinite" case, since it appears that `v2` has type `forall t140. Extended t140`.  I'm assuming t140 is some sort of placeholder the compiler automatically fills in.  The type of v1 is `Extended Int`.  So if I setup an instance of Eq to compare values of Extended, the Infinite case does not match...

```
instance extendedEq :: (Eq a) => Eq (Extended a) where
  eq (Finite a) (Finite b) = eq a b
  eq Infinite Infinite = true
  eq Infinite _ = false
  eq _ Infinite = false
```

So when I try and run `v2 == v2` I get the error...

```
No type class instance was found for Prelude.Eq (Extended _0)
```

Which makes sense, since I imagine it's trying to find an Eq instance for t140.

So my question is, how can I pattern matching on the Infinite type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not about pattern matching or your instance implementation. Your ADT has the same structure as `Maybe`, and if I try

```
main = print (Nothing == Nothing)
```

I get the error code: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Error-Code-NoInstanceFound

Your type parameter *t140* could be anything in the `Eq` type class, so the compiler is not able to select an instance. You need to add a type annotation to at least one of the operands of `==`:

```
v2 = Infinite :: Extended Int
```

But I admit it would be more satisfactory if the compiler could figure out that `Infinite == Infinite` for any (same) type parameter...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense to me now.